# When downloading HTML in C#, how can I have the website use the settings stored by my browser

Tags: c#, html, cookies, httpwebrequest

I need to download the HTML source from a particular website.

The website has a number of settings that may be configured without logging in. The settings must be stored using cookies stored on the local computer.

When I download the source using C# the website does not use those cookies stored by my browser. The HTML I download is the "vanilla" version with the default settings, rather than the settings I previously chose in my browser.

Is there any way to use the cookies stored by my browser?

Comment: No, and you shouldn't want to. Recreate the cookies when you perform the web request.

Comment: OK that sounds promising. So do I look up the cookies that are currently stored by the website? Right now I have very little understanding of cookies. If you can let me know a good resource to read up on them (knowing how I want to use them) I would appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: @AndrewScott you _CAN_ access the cookies from another browser. There are a few screen scraping libraries for .net that can accomplish this but each one is different and really depends on your requirements. I am most often recommending [Teleriks free testing framework](http://www.telerik.com/teststudio/testing-framework) as it is constantly updating and fixing bugs and supports many different browsers. I have 2 questions for you: 1) Which browser do you need the cookies from? and, 2) Do you need to distribute your software to other people or is it for your own personal use?

Comment: Hi Joey,

In the end I did manage to create the cookie I needed. I looked at the cookies in Chrome and found the specific one I needed. Luckily it was pretty easy to find and a very small cookie.

I was able to create the cookie object manually, add it to the cookie collection with the httpwebrequest and have it sent to the site. This resulted in the source code including the data I needed.

In this case it was nothing more complex than setting just one setting, so right now I don't need anything as advanced as what you are recommending. Thanks for getting back to me.